# Adverb oder nachgestelltes Adjektiv? Schillers Glocke

Tags: adverb, genitive, adjective

> Kocht des Kupfers Brei!
> Schnell das Zinn herbei,
> Daß die zähe Glockenspeise,
> fließe nach der rechten Weise!

Das ist aus Schillers "Glocke", ab Zeile 25.

> "...nach der rechten Weise":

öhm... Ist das Dativ???

Zweite Frage: Ist das ein Adverb?

Beispiele aus dem Duden:
Präfix: nachstarren, Nachmessung, nachfeiern, etc.
Präposition: nach Berlin, nach Ablauf der Frist, ...
Adverb: Mir nach! Nach und nach, nach wie vor, ...

Es fließt auf die richtige Art. "Auf die richtige Art" bezieht sich auf fließen, also ist es ein Adverb? Entsprechend auch mein Beispiel oben?

Comment: Ist was ein Adverb?

Comment: @CarstenS Hab' auch gerätselt. "Nach" ist  wohl gemeint.

Comment: @Hilmar Ich schlage vor, in der Frage genauer anzugeben, worauf sich das *das*  in *Ist **das** ein Adverb?* bezieht oder entsprechend zu ersetzen: *Ist "XYZ" ein Adverb?*

Comment: Wie schön und klar man hier mal wieder sieht, wer alles um die Wurst springt! Zwei Fragen  - wie du selbst sagst - sind zwei Fragen! Dann stelle doch bitte auch zwei Fragen!

Comment: Was bedeutet die Formulierung "Wer alles um die Wurst springt"?

Answer (score 4):

Der Satzteil

> nach der rechten Weise

ist eine adverbiale Bestimmung oder Adverbial, im speziellen Fall ein Modaladverbial, hat die gleiche Funktion wie ein Adverb und könnte durch ein Adverb mit ähnlicher Bedeutung ersetzt werden, z.B. "*ordnungsgemäß*" oder "*richtig*".

Die Stellung nach dem Verb ergibt sich im angegebenen Beispiel aus der Gedichtsform; im normalen Sprachgebrauch würde man das Adverbial oder ein Adverb in einem Nebensatz eher vor das Verb setzen.

siehe auch [Wikipedia: Adverbiale Bestimmung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbiale_Bestimmung)

Das Wort "*nach*" für sich allein ist eine Präposition, die den Dativ verlangt.

Answer (score 1):

Weder Adverb noch Adjektiv - sondern Präposition (genau so wie sein Synonym *gemäß*). Und ja, sowohl *gemäß* als auch das in dieser Bedeutung verwendete *nach* fordern den Dativ.